# How to detect changes in model of element?

Tags: angularjs

I have model: `$scope.genres = [object: {id: 1, list: []}]`

How to detect changes in model only element `$scope.genres.list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can $scope.$watch to watch the changes in the model.

Please refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: I tried: `$scope.$watch('genre.list', function() { });`

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other option but detect changes, then you can use watch:

```
$scope.$watch('genres.list', function(newValue) {
    //...code...
}, true); //"true" provides deep watch (for inner properties)
```